# Add to a node's run list during chef-client execution

Tags: chef-infra

I have many ephemeral nodes in open stack under Chef management.  While chef-client is running, I'd like to dynamically assign roles to them based on their host name, but I haven't found documentation or examples of how it might be done.  Is this even supported?  Is it an anti-pattern?

Comment: Based on the phases of a chef-run, I'd say that you can't easily synchronize the cookbooks again and thus change your run list during a chef run. What you can do is to override the run list at start of the chef-client run. So if you trigger another chef-client through the intial chef-client run.. uff.. maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no good way to do this. You can mutate a node's run list by altering `node.run_list` in your code, but this will have no effect until the next run. Additionally I (and some other core devs) think that this being allowed by default is something that should be fixed as it makes using the run list for security-ish identification impossible. A better approach would be to make a top-level cookbook which depends on everything, and uses some Ruby code to do node classification and runs the appropriate recipes using `include_recipe`. The downside is this means you need to sync down every cookbook that could be used, which takes a while the first time. Additionally you have to load all the attributes files et al, which isn't the slowest thing ever, but it can be undesirable for other reasons.